# Why does tokio::spawn not require Sync?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

The doc says

> The spawned task may execute on the current thread, or it may be sent to a different thread to be executed.

So if you share a variable which is `!Sync` between two async blocks and spawn them, they may be executed simultaneously, which induces race condition.

How does tokio deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spawning an async task (future) requires that it is `Send`. If two futures share access to something that is not `Sync`, then the future itself will not be `Send`. This is not something specific to Tokio or to async; notice that [`std::thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) has the same requirement of `Send + 'static` on the spawned function.

The way this works is that anything that allows access to a value from multiple threads (such as `Arc` or `&`) will have a conditional implementation for `Send` like this one (from the standard library code for `Arc`):

```rust
unsafe impl<T: ?Sized + Sync + Send> Send for Arc<T> {}
```

This says: An `Arc<T>` will not be `Send` unless its contents `T` are `Sync`.

Anything you can find that will allow you to “share a variable” will similarly enforce that the data that is shared must be `Sync`.